# Detect variable change

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program to constantly check for a change in variable throughout the running of the program. Does this require an infinite loop in a thread?

Comment: This really depends on why you need to trace the variable. If it just a most-modification action, you are probably fine with providing a setter method, like The1 proposed. If the problem concerns multiple threads (even a simple checker thread), you immediately have a whole new set of things to consider.

Answer (score 1):

There are better options than periodically polling the value of the variable. Polling could miss a variable change, and it requires computational resources even if nothing is happening.

You could wrap the variable in a wrapper class and change it only through a setter.

If you're using Eclipse, you can ask the debugger to stop whenever the value changes.

Comment: You can also detect variable changes [using an event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247926/java-event-listener-to-detect-a-variable-change).

Comment: @AndersonGreen - yes, and fire the event through the setter mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Using a wrapper class for you variable like:

```
class VarWrapper{
    private Object myVar;

    public Object getMyVar() {
        return myVar;
    }
    public void setMyVar(Object myVar) {
        //[1],Here you'll know myVar changed
        this.myVar = myVar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Test{
   private int var;

   public void setVariable(int var){
     this.var = var;
     varChangedCallBack(); 
   }

   public void varChangedCallBack(){
      //Do something on var changed
   }
}
```

As the variable is private above, it can be changed only thr' setter.After changing we are giving call to callback method, in which you can do whatever you like to do on variable change.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dedicated thread to check the variable state then it should be done with wakening up this waiting thread with sync-notify on the object. The waiting thread is going to sync-wait on that object.

If you do not have a dedicated thread then this the Observer pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern